# Custom PermissionEvaluator doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I tried to write own impementation of PermissionEvaluator. Here it is:

```
public class PermissionEvaluatorImpl implements PermissionEvaluator {
public PermissionEvaluatorImpl() {
}

@Override
public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Object targetDomainObject, Object permission) {
    final CustomUser customUser = (CustomUser) authentication.getPrincipal();
    //Some custom logic
    System.out.println("TEST");
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Serializable targetId, String targetType, Object permission) {
    System.out.println("TEST");
    return false;
}
}
```

The main problem, how I understood is saying to `DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler`, that It must use mine. I tried to do it many ways:

```
@Bean
DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler defaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler(){
    DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler defaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler = new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
    defaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler.setPermissionEvaluator(new PermissionEvaluatorImpl());
    return defaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler;
}
```

Tried to autowire it (because it's annotated @Component, I can change it's field after all initializations), but it isn't still working.
I also tried to make my PermissionEvaluator @Component, then set it in DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler's field. This way was the same (nothing works).
I also thought, that I put `@PreAuthorize` in incorrect place, so I marked with this annotation all layers (Controller,Service,DAO). Still not working

Comment: What errors it's producing? You should know that questions without clear problem statement are off-topic on SO and the code should be MCVE.

Comment: No errors are producing. Just hasPermission() methods aren't invocating.

Comment: This is not enough for the answer.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Can you post the exact code you're using for the `@PreAuthorize`?  I'm able to get this working (albeit with XML config)

Comment: Have you added this to your config class: @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)